# How to get Markdown preview in the Monaco Editor?

Tags: monaco-editor

VSCode has for .md markdown files, "Open Preview". How to get that same functionality? Is it included? I looked through the playground examples and the API, but do not see anything. Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

This functionality is not part of Monaco.

I wouldn't bother with trying to get the preview into Monaco itself; just grab the markdown content from the editor, pass it through a markdown rendering engine like [markdown-it](https://github.com/markdown-it/markdown-it), and preview the generated html in a iframe or similar. See the [markdown-it demo](https://markdown-it.github.io) for inspiration

Comment: Will take a look. Thanks. Anyone know how it is done in VSCode? Thanks.

Comment: VS Code uses a [webview](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensions/webview) to display html content generated by markdown-it ([relevant extension source](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/blob/master/extensions/markdown-language-features/src/features/preview.ts)). I'm the developer of VSCode's built-in markdown extension

Answer (score 1):

There is a renderMarkdown method in markdownRenderer.js with monaco-editor library, this method helps convert markdown to HTML which can then be rendered inside a div's innerHTML.

```js
import { renderMarkdown } from "monaco-editor/esm/vs/base/browser/markdownRenderer"

const htmlResult = renderMarkdown({
            value: samplemarkdownData
        }).innerHTML;
```

> Paths may vary for different monaco-editor versions. monaco-editor v0.27.0 was used as a reference here.

Comment: Does this remove markup characters or only apply coloring?

Comment: Note that this uses the "marked" library ([source](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/tree/main/src/vs/base/common/marked)) instead of "markdown-it" used for the "Markdown language feature"